# What would be an efficient way to set up this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I'm trying to create a web application to organize a user's TV interests, to do this, I need to store data of three types: `Shows`, `Seasons`, and `Episodes`.

I would like to query my data like this: `Show.find(1).season(2).episode.each`. This should return each episode of the second season of the show with the `id` 1. How can I set my model up to a achieve this?

I've tried having values of `season_id` and `show_id` on the `episodes`, but its unable to find the `episodes` belonging to each `season`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a good idea to read through the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). Assuming that your entity relationships looking like this:

[image: erd]

You can implement this with `activerecord` easily. The models would look like this:

```
require 'active_record'

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :seasons
end

class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
    has_many :episodes
end

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season
end
```

Your migrations could look like:

```
require 'active_record'

class CreateShows < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :shows do |t|
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end

class CreateSeasons < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :seasons do |t|
            t.references :show, :null => false
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end

class CreateEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :episodes do |t|
            t.references :season, :null => false
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

Put some data into your database and query them with:

```
Show.find(1).seasons.first.episodes.each{ |e| puts e.title }
```

Comment: in the migrations, if i put "t.references :season",etc. , would i still need to have data like 'season_id' and 'show_id' for seasons and episodes.

Comment: No, because `t.references` will cause a `id` attribute (foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

Define relationship in mode,

```
Show
 has_many :seasons

Season
 has_many :episodes
 belongs_to :show

Episode
 belongs_to :season
```

Then you can call like this,

```
Show.find(1).seasons.first.episodes.each {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are great; I'd take it a step further and use has_many's **:through** option in the Show model and **has_one :through** on the Episode model:

```
# Show

has_many :seasons
has_many :episodes, through: :seasons

# Season

belongs_to :show
has_many   :episodes

# Episode

belongs_to :season
has_one    :show, through: :season
```

This lets you make calls like this:

```
Show.first.episodes
Episode.first.show
```

... and will also allow you to write some query-minimizing scopes, and write delegate methods that simplifying finding related information.

```
# Episode
delegate   :name, to: :show, prefix: :show

Episode.first.show_name # => Episode.first.show.name
```